# get the abbreviation of yesterday within batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to get the yesterday date but as abbervation like `MON` `FRI` `THU`...
etc... below code will retrun the yesterday date as digits

anyway to get the abbreviation from it ?

or is there any other simple way to do it with out form loop .\

NOTE

`powershell` way wont work because my business requirement is to work under `windows xp`

```
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/- " %%a in ('date/T') do set DATE=%%c

for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/- " %%a in ('date/T') do set /a DAY=%%c

set /a YESTERDAY = DATE - 1
echo %YESTERDAY%%
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirement to support an operating system five generations old, perhaps this untested example will suffice:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1Tokens=2-4Delims=(-/)" %%A In ('"Date<Nul"'
) Do For /F "Tokens=1-3Delims=/" %%a In ("%DATE%"
) Do Set "%%A=%%a" & Set "%%B=%%b" & Set "%%C=%%c"
Set/A mm=10%mm%%%100,dd=10%dd%%%100
If %mm% Lss 3 Set/A mm+=12,yy-=1
Set/A a=yy/100,b=a/4,c=2-a+b,e=36525*(yy+4716)/100,f=306*(mm+1)/10,^
 dow=(c+dd+e+f-1523)%%7+1
For /F "Tokens=%dow%" %%A In ("Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri") Do Set "yddd=%%A"
Echo [%yddd%]
Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dos something like this :

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('powershell ^(get-date^).DayOfWeek') do set dow=%%i
echo %dow:~0,3%
```

or using `wmic` (more code but more eficient!)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

For /F "skip=2 tokens=2 delims==" %%a In ( 'wmic path win32_localtime get dayofweek /Value' ) Do set /a wd=%%a-1

if %wd%==1 set $wd=MON
if %wd%==2 set $wd=TUE
if %wd%==3 set $wd=WED
if %wd%==4 set $wd=THU
if %wd%==5 set $wd=FRI
if %wd%==6 set $wd=SAT
if %wd%==7 set $wd=SUN

echo Yesterdey was =^> %$wd%
```

Comment: SachaDee, just to note that the `XP` OS mentioned in the question excludes the use of `PowerShell`, _(I made the same mistake myself)_; and `WMIC` is not available on all versions of `XP` either.